# Whether to include view specific information in model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, c#-4.0

I currently have a class containing the following properties

```
public class Chromosome
{
    public int Length
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Number
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Chromosome(int _length, int _number)
    {
        Length = _length;
        Number = _number;
    }
}
```

I have a list box data binded to my view model. The items source is data binded to a **Observable** of Chromosome objects **ChromosomeList**.

```
<Grid>
        <ListBox Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}"  
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChromosomeList}"
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChromosomeDataTemplate}">
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

The ItemTemplate for the list box items is **ChromosomeDataTemplate** and is shown below.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ChromosomeDataTemplate">
    <Border>
        <Grid Height="10">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                       Text="{Binding Number}">
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

In this case, I want the **Height** property of the grid to be data binded to the **Length** property of the chromosome. However, as the **Length** is extremely large, I need it to be a small percentage of the actual value. I could do this by:

- Making a new property specific for the modified height

However, I feel that this does not follow the MVVM Pattern. Is there any way to modify the **Length** value when data binding it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Chromosome` is your Model. Your XAML code resides in your View. The hypothetical "modified-length" value should reside in your ViewModel.

You are correct in saying that making a new property for the modified height is not MVVM (and is a very bad idea generally, of course).

For a better approach, you would normally put the modified-length property in the ViewModel. However your problem is now that your ViewModel has an `ObservableCollection<Chromosome>` and therefore cannot provide a simple modified-length property for each one of the `Chromosome` instances.

Therefore, you have two choices:

1. Implement a [`ValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that translates the original `Length` to an appopriate `Grid.Height`. This could be either in your ViewModel or the View, but I think putting it in the ViewModel is not appropriate (since it will be used by a specific View only). This is the simplest approach.
2. Wrap every `Chromosome` in its own ViewModel, e.g. `ChromosomeViewModel`. Your existing ViewModel would take a collection of `Chromosome`s and expose an `ObservableCollection<ChromosomeViewModel>`. You would then create a `ChromosomeView` bound to each ViewModel, which would basically be what you have now in your `ChromosomeDataTemplate`. Since the `ChromosomeView` will be bound to a `ChromosomeViewModel`, which in turn wraps a single `Chromosome`, you can now provide a "modified-length" property directly in your `ChromosomeViewModel`.

If it's just for this, I suggest going with the `ValueConverter`. However, keep the second approach in mind for more complex scenarios.

Comment: Its just for this. I will encapsulate future collections in View Models.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a ValueConverter : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a converter here? See e.g. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#data_conversion)